# KDM accepting username and password but doesn't load desktop

Tags: 14.04, login, password, kde

I installed kde with sudo apt-get install kde-full on my ubuntu 14.04 desktop, then I got a warning about running out of space (I can't remember it exactly) and kde was still installing so I killed the process and tried to uninstall it but it wouldn't let me as a process was still running? Anyway I rebooted the computer and it now boots to the kdm login screen which accepts my username and password but then nothing loads, I just have the kdm wallpaper and a cursor.

I have seen it's something about lightdm but how can I change to this?

Comment: There should be a menu on the login screen to change which desktop environment you want to use. Make sure Ubuntu Desktop is selected and not KDE. When you log in, run `sudo apt-get purge kde-* kubuntu-*`.

Comment: I selected ubuntu but its still not loading anything. Can I do the purge via the ubuntu recovery mode "drop to shell" option?

Comment: It would be better to try a TTY: ctrl + alt + f1, log in here, run the command above, then run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Thankyou! I got it all back!! I was having major panics as I have some unbacked up PhD work on that computer and I feared I'd never see it again.

Comment: Oh, there was definitely no data loss. You'd just be left with no GUI :p.

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KDE is **huge**, so it's not very surprising that you ran out of space. Next time, though, try to resolve before you reboot. It can save you a lot of headache.

Follow these steps to restore normal Unity.

1. Enter a TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Log in with your username and password.
3. Run `sudo apt-get purge kde-* kubuntu-*`.
4. Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.
5. Reboot.
6. You should be back to LightDM, and Unity should start when you log in.

   - Make sure that `Ubuntu Desktop` is selected in the menu at the top right of the password box. If this menu doesn't exist, that's fine. Just log in.